# replace a text in PDF with current design, PHP

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf, fpdf

We are trying to replace a text in PDF, But when we are doing this our current design is removed, Like page background color and images. Is there any free PHP library available which maintain current design and replace text or string from current PDF?

UPDATE:-

As helper suggest we can use TCPDF, We are using this but text is not replacing.

Here is our code:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en">
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="charset=UTF-8"></head>
<?php
require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
$pdf_content = file_get_contents("a.pdf");
echo $pdf_content;
$put = str_replace('HARRY', 'Ankur', $pdf_content);
file_put_contents('test.pdf', $put);
?>
</html>
```

echo $pdf_content output is something like this

```
 X/ �7�B�P�z}�����Ha�%z�p�i�ڵ}�~��vH;��Nh��.��ѣ�=W�Ӈ�����XEq�ی�����F���{�����k��>�>�=I�J�������tSw��~�~�>H�߬Q�U�M�C��ь�]���%�P̚,��fe��M٫�W��4ΐH���ܦ�ɩ6�>�����w
```

Comment: Sorry, but it is impossible to answer to such a vague question. Packages like `tcpdf` certainly do _not_ remove anything from their output, just because you change a text. So the question is: what is wrong in your code that things do not work as expected. But for us to help with that you obviously will have to post the relevant parts of your code...

Comment: OK. Sorry. Please wait i will add our code in question

Comment: How about exporting PDF to HTML, replace and convert it back again?

Comment: PDF to html and again back to new PDF. Read somewhere when we convert PDF we loose some data. so PDF-->HTML and HTML--->PDF same PDF i think not possible. @Xorifelse

Comment: Obviously that will not work, you include a class and don't use it? Secondly the [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/index.php) website states it's used for generating PDF documents, not reading them. Take a look at [pdfparser](http://www.pdfparser.org/) instead.

Answer (score -1):

You need to access to core pdf and re generate another one. the solution is a commercial software calls SetaPDF-Core.